# Add UILabel to the left side of a UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to consolidate screen space in my iPhone app by putting label text inside of a UITextField that will be uneditable. It will tell the user what to put into the text field. Here is an example of an app that does exactly what I want to do.

[image]

I have done my research and found some code to mimic this to some extent.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 40)];
label.text= @"Exerise Name:";
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
_txtExerciseName.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
_txtExerciseName.leftView = label;

[self.view addSubview:_txtExerciseName];
```

This is inside viewDidLoad. The code yields something like this:

[image]

Obviously with styling and tweaking this might work but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this that I am not seeing. If someone has any tips, ideas, or code samples to get me going in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Having both a label and the placeholder is redundant. There is no need for the label. Just use the text field's placeholder.

Comment: You could always just have 3 elements: the background image, the label, and the text field. Then you can customize each separately and not have to manipulate the UITextView properties too much.

Comment: It looks to me like you found exactly what you need. I did not know about overlay views, UITextFieldViewModeAlways, or the leftView property of UITextFields, but looking at the docs it looks like they support exactly what you are after. The look of UIElements has changed a lot between iOS 6 and iOS 7. I would bet that the look you posted for the "Exerise Name" field (sic) is in an app built for, and running under iOS 7, and the sample screen from SunTrust is an iOS 6 app (even if it is running under iOS 7.) Try playing with the borderStyle property.

Answer (score 2):

I saw a really cool solution to this problem. The placeholder text is moved to the top of the textfield when the keyboard comes up/becomes the first responder, then disappears when the textfield resigns the first responder.

Implementations

- [Objective-C](https://github.com/jverdi/JVFloatLabeledTextField)
- [Swift](https://github.com/meismyles/FloatLabelFields)

Comment: [Here is a project](https://github.com/meismyles/FloatLabelFields) that is currently maintained that makes this interface very simple to implement (not mine).

Comment: Thanks, I added a link to that project as a Swift implementation

Answer (score 1):

The effect you're trying to mimic is almost certainly done by:

- Creating what looks like a text box image in an image editing app, importing into your project -- you could also do it via slices so you can create any width field background.
- Place the aforementioned image where you want the label and text field
- Place a borderless UILabel and a borderless UITextField in the appropriate spot above the image you just dropped.

That should do it. No code changes necessary.

Comment: A little surprised you've not marked as correct mine, nor the other answer, nor appeared to up vote any of the comments. Did none of our suggestions help?